# Writing an appspec.yml File for Deployment from GitHub to AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-code-deploy

I'd like to make it so that a commit to our GitHub repo automatically deploys code (using CodeDeploy) to our EC2 instances.  I'm not clear what to use for the 'source' entry  under the 'files' section in the appspec.yml file.  I've found some examples for using a local git repo, but I was wondering if someone could help me out?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The appspec.yml roots all paths for `source` files (and scripts) to the archive bundle's root. The `destination` paths are rooted in the system root.

This appspec.yml would copy all files from the `foo` directory of your archive bundle recursively to `/www/foo-app/` on your system.

```
files:
  - source: /foo
    destination: /www/foo-app/
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref.html or http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-add-appspec-file.html for a more detailed reference on the appspec.yml file.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  This is sort along the lines of what I'm trying to figure out.  I've seen the documentation on the ApPSpec reference guide, but I don't quite know what you mean by "archive bundle's root".  If I have a repo called 'CodeRepo' on GitHub, and I wanted to get a file from the 'src' directory from 'CodeRepo', what would I put in the 'source' section of my AppSpec file?

Comment: When the host agent downloads your repo, the repo's root is the archive root (there's an intermediate archive generated by GitHub). So the get files from the `src` directory of your repo you'd need to use `/src/` in your appspec.yml.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using CodePipeline? It does exactly what you are looking for.

You can specify the github source in Code pipeline, and when there is a commit, it can deploy to your "code deploy" fleet. Of course you can do much more with pipeline.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/welcome.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: snannapa, thanks for you response.  CodePipeline is an excellent choice for the workflow I'm looking for.  The problem is that I'm still faced with the same question as above.  CodePipeline can use CodeDeploy to ingest my GitHub code, but how do I tell it where, exactly, to deploy the code to?  This my be done in the AppSpec file as far as I know but I don't know how to structure the 'files' section.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a native way to do what you are looking for.

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx33XKAKURCCW83/Automatically-Deploy-from-GitHub-Using-AWS-CodeDeploy